# JSP taglib fmt and t fails on tomcat 9 upgrade

Tags: jsp, taglib, tomcat9

What I see is with tomcat 9  doc "JspContextWrapper" has a new parameter "JspTag jspTag" and tomcat 7 does not have the New parameter

[Tomcat 9 Doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspContextWrapper.html)

[Tomcat 7 Doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspContextWrapper.html)

I have made sure no multiple jar versions are loaded.

Below is the exception i am getting.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspContextWrapper.<init>(Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspContext;Ljava/util/ArrayList;Ljava/util/ArrayList;Ljava/util/ArrayList;Ljava/util/Map;)V
        at org.apache.jsp.tag.webhelp_tag.setJspContext(webhelp_tag.java:38)
```

Alternatively, I was able to bring in the tablib change inline inside the jsp which was failing, and remove @tablib it works.
But want to know if someone has faced this issue and making changes in all JSP's, I feel is not a simple approach.

Comment: Did you check if you don't have stale files in the `work` directory, still compiled by Tomcat 7?

Comment: Yes, no stale files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jsp strange error when migrating tomcat and java versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561576/jsp-strange-error-when-migrating-tomcat-and-java-versions)

Comment: I did Could not find any solution  in time, hence had to remove @tablib dependence altogether and make changes respectively.